# JSON parsing error for IP addresses

Tags: java

I have the below JSON string -

```
"abc":["17.14.4.0/14"]
"def":["12.24.82.0/14","17.15.146.38"]
```

I have the below method that displays all the IPs in abc, def, and every string contained within my JSON string (There are close to 100).

```
private static List<String> listOfAllIPs = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> getListOfIps(String networkID)
{           
    SubnetUtils utils = new SubnetUtils(networkID);
    String[] ipArr = utils.getInfo().getAllAddresses();
    List<String> ipList = Arrays.asList(ipArr);     
    return ipList;
}
for(String networkIP:IPList) //IP list is the list of all the IPs - I have pasted sample IP list below
    {       
    listOfAllIPs.addAll(getListOfIps(networkIP));           
    }

IP List -
17.24.84.0/24
17.24.80.0/24
63.92.240.160/28
12.43.176.137/28
17.24.86.0/25
17.24.92.0/24
```

I can't paste my entire code here. This is the issue I am having. My method works perfectly when it has to get the IPs for abc. But for the string def, it is throwing the below error -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse [12.24.82.0/14]
at org.apache.commons.net.util.SubnetUtils.calculate(SubnetUtils.java:217)
at org.apache.commons.net.util.SubnetUtils.<init>(SubnetUtils.java:52)
```

My team mates and I have been struggling to figure out how to resolve this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Which version of commons-net are you using?

Comment: Try inspecting each character of your subnet mask and see if they're ASCII chars and not some strange character looking the same. Try entering in debug mode into the SubnetUtils.calculate() to see what's wrong. Given the source code, I can't find where the problem comes from.